# The difference between "Ereignis" and "Vorkommen"

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference between *Ereignis* and *Vorkommen*. I keep on needing explanation in this question even so some can think it's nonsense.

If someone, in Hedegger's understanding, could explain me, it would be even more thankful.

Comment: I can give you the definitions in various scientific fields, but I doubt, that Heidegger used scientific terms.

Comment: @Tosho, I would be already grateful with this definitions because it could illuminate my understanding.

Comment: Welche eigenen Bemühungen wurden unternommen die Frage selbständig zu lösen? Ist an die Konsultation eines Wörterbuchs gedacht worden?

Answer (score 4):

Because it's explicitely asked for, I give some definitions for `Ereignis` and `Vorkommen` in some scientific fields. Feel free to add others.

## Ereignis

### Probability theory

`Ereignis` is a subset of a sample space.

### Physics

`Ereignis` is a single element of the spacetime.

### Astronomy

`Ereignis` is any observable phenomenon in the sky.

## Vorkommen

### Geology

`Vorkommen` is any local amount of ore, minerals or rock.

### Geography without Geology

`Vorkommen` is any local, regional or national amount of any economic ressource.

### Biology

`Vorkommen` is the set of individuals of a given species living in a specific area.

Comment: I think *Ereignis* exists in probability. I don't see the reason to constrain that concept to stochastic processes. (Aber vielleicht Heidegger hätte nichts dagegen `:)`)

Comment: @c.p. I don't get you meaning.

Comment: I'm ok with "Ereignis is a subset of a sample space.", but the title (stochastics) is quite restrictive. [Ereignis](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ereignis_%28Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie%29) exists in probability theory, which is broader than "stochastics".

Comment: @c.p. OK, I'm not aware of any difference in the terms "stochastics" and "probability theory".

Comment: Aus Wikipedia „Gemeinsam mit der mathematischen Statistik, die anhand von Beobachtungen zufälliger Vorgänge Aussagen über das zugrunde liegende Modell trifft, bildet sie das mathematische Teilgebiet der Stochastik.“ ME nach hat die Stochastik einen impliziten Geschmack nach zeitlicher Entwiklung.

Answer (score 2):

*Ereignis* is translated with **event**. While *Vorkommen* is translated with **occurrence**.

Answer (score 1):

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ereignis
In no. 2 Heidegger's Ereignis is explained.